# Apache: use `foo.html` in preference to `foo/` when both exist

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to get Apache 2.2 to use `foo.html` in preference to `foo/` when both exist?

I'm moving a site from dynamic php to static html, while retaining the domain name. I've created a temporary mirror using [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/). The mirror site works well, except that pages which used to be `foo/about` are now `foo/about.html`. When I replace the live site with the mirror all incoming links and bookmarks will be broken, something I want to avoid.

I've discovered using `Options +MultiViews` in my .htaccess file achieves most of the above, except when file and directory names collide: if the url is `http://example.org/how_to` apache tries to load `how_to/index.*` instead of `how_to.html` when the latter exists.

I've tried a few mod_rewrite rule sets but only succeeded in duplicating the multiviews behaviour at the expense of a more complicated .htaccess file:

```
# Add .html internally (but remove externally):
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteBase   /

# Skip the next 2 rules (the .html stripping redirections)
# if the current URL doesn't end with .html
# or the requested file doesn't exist:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\.html\    [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .? - [S=2]

# Redirect /dir/index.html to /dir/:
RewriteRule ^(.*/|)index\.html$   $1 [R=301,L]
# Redirect /dir/file.html to /dir/file:
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$   $1 [R=301,L]

# Internally, treat request for /dir/file as /dir/file.html
# (but only if /dir/file.html exists):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html   [L]
```

As you've likely surmised by now. I'm on a shared host and can only use `.htaccess` directives. This is static html, php, cgi, etc. are not available.

Hat tip to *cjm* and *pne* on the [nearlyfreespeech.net forum](https://members.nearlyfreespeech.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=31062) who got me this far.

Comment: I note there are two close votes in less than 30 minutes. Anyone care to explain what's wrong or unwelcome about the question? Txs.

Comment: @ziesemer, thanks. I didn't know about webmasters.SE. I asked here because there are >8k htaccess questions present, vs <1K at ServerFault.com. I guess the network is big enough now there needs to be a "where do I ask my question?" question...  Should I wait for a mod to move this to webmasters or just delete and repost there myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) appears to be thwarting your efforts. Give this a try instead:

```
DirectorySlash off

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html   -f
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L,QSA]
```

Comment: *thank you!* so very much. I've spent hours and hours trying to figure out the right parameters and syntax. To have it boiled down to just 4 lines and *just work* is sweet indeed.